# How can we add two function on (click) event in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to call 2 methods on (click) of a button. Is there any way in Angular5.

Comment: call a method that calls two other methods? Or just call your two methods directly from (click), but that's ugly. Why don't you at least try?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for sharing your idea. I will try it.

Comment: Can you show some codes - the two methods and button having click event.

Comment: Thanks, @JBNizet, I have achieved the required functionality using your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do this

```
<div (click)="methodt1(); method2()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two option for this -

> Option 1 : Inline call

Put into click separated by comma

```
 <input (click)="fun1(); fun2()")/>
```

> Option 2 : Recommended way

You can write one more function in ts file which will call those two methods.

***html***

```
<input (click)="callMe()")/>
```

***ts***

```
  callMe(){
     fun1();
     fun2();
  }

  fun1(){
   ...
  }

  fun2(){
    ...
  }
```